# How should I write JUnit for this function

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
public static Map<String,SrnPastPricing> parseFile(String fileLoc) throws IOException {
    String fileAsString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(FilenameUtils.normalize(fileLoc)));
    fileAsString = fileAsString.replace("\r", "");
    String[] lines = fileAsString.split("\\n");
    String headingsRow = lines[0];
    String[] headings = headingsRow.split(",");
    System.out.println("Reading first line as the heading row...");

    Map<String,SrnPastPricing> pastPricingMap = new HashMap<String,SrnPastPricing>();
    for (int x = 1; x < lines.length; x++) {
        SrnPastPricing pastPricing = parseLine(lines[x], headings);
        pastPricingMap.put(pastPricing.ClaimId, pastPricing);
    }
    return pastPricingMap;
}
```

I tried to mock it and returning the map, but it's asking for the exact location of the file and doesn't work with random string argument and throwing Null pointer Exception.

```
SrnPastPricing mockSrnPastPricing = Mockito.spy(srnPastPricing);
Mockito.doReturn(mockMap).when(mockSrnPastPricing).parseFile("file\\loc\\file.txt");
```

Please tell me the write way to mock it.

Comment: I'd suggest you to break this method into much smaller pieces which will read the file n give you `headings`. Now you can mock `FileUtils.readFileToString(anyString())` using something like a Mockito library.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a static file I usually put an example file inside the `src/resources` folder and load the file from class-path.

If you are running inside instance, `this.getClass().getResource("/log4j.properties").getFile()`.

If you are running as a static method, `CurrentJavaClassName.class.getResource("/log4j.properties").getFile()`

Answer (score 0):

Make method testable by passing fileAsString as param. So your method should look like this:

```
public static Map<String,SrnPastPricing> parseFile(String fileAsString) throws IOException {
    fileAsString = fileAsString.replace("\r", "");
    String[] lines = fileAsString.split("\\n");
    String headingsRow = lines[0];
    String[] headings = headingsRow.split(",");
    System.out.println("Reading first line as the heading row...");

    Map<String,SrnPastPricing> pastPricingMap = new HashMap<String,SrnPastPricing>();
    for (int x = 1; x < lines.length; x++) {
        SrnPastPricing pastPricing = parseLine(lines[x], headings);
        pastPricingMap.put(pastPricing.ClaimId, pastPricing);
    }
    return pastPricingMap;
}
```

And somewhere in you code you will call it like:

```
String fileAsString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(FilenameUtils.normalize(fileLoc)));
if (fileAsString != null) {
parseFile(fileAsString);
}
```

That is the easiest way and the right one.

Comment: Your solution is working, but I am not allowed to modify the function.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the file in this way :

```
File resourcesDirectory = new File("src/test/resources/data/request/ParseFile");
resourceDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: This will work great inside IDE. Please make sure the code works outside IDE. Like your CI